# Global Not Working

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a file in PHP with a large array and a function that searches the array.

Heres the code:

```
$details = array(

  array('fieldID'=>'0','fieldCaption'=>'Address 1','fieldType'=>'text','fieldName'=>'addr1','fieldRequired'=>'1'),
  array('fieldID'=>'1','fieldCaption'=>'Address 2','fieldType'=>'text','fieldName'=>'addr2','fieldRequired'=>'1'),
  .
  .
  .
);

if(!function_exists('find_detail'))
{
  function find_detail($fieldName)
  {
    global $details;
    var_dump($details); // NULL

    foreach ($details as $detail)
    {
      if($detail['fieldName'] == $fieldName)
      {
        return $detail['fieldID'];
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

This sits inside a single helper file and calling var_dump($details); is returning NULL. I suspect an issue with scoping.

Many Thanks

-- edit --

This is bad practice and the best approach to handling this would be (as @Gordon stated) to pass the details array into the function. (Warning: There exist better ways of doing this, for example using array_filter)

```
if(!function_exists('find_detail_by_field_name'))
{
  function find_detail_by_field_name($details, $fieldName)
  {
    foreach ($details as $detail)
    {
      if($detail['fieldName'] == $fieldName)
      {
        return $detail['fieldID'];
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

And provide a way to get the details, wrapping details in a function would provide many benefits such as caching, change of source etc.

```
function get_details() 
{
   static $details = array(...)
   return $details;
}
```

Comment: Global state is BAD.  Avoid it at all costs.  Pass your array into the function as an argument or define the array inside the function itself instead.

Comment: Wouldn't defining it inside the function be heavy on memory? I'll be calling this function many times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your function operates on that `$details` array, it should ask for that array in the function signature. Anything else is just hiding dependencies and is hard to debug and maintain (as you can see by the need to ask your question). So change it to

```
function find_detail($fieldName, array $details)
```

and foreach over the passed in array then.

Also, since the function really returns the fieldId and not some detail, you might want to rename it to

```
function findFieldIdByFieldName($fieldName, array $details)
```

**But to answer your question:** you likely get this effect because you created the $details array outside the global scope, the topmost scope of your script. If you defined $details in a function or a method or if it is included in the scope of another function, it is not in the global scope.

Comment: This would require me to pass the array on call wouldn't it?

Comment: @Eddie Yes. Clean and simple.

Comment: As the array sits inside a codeigniter helper, I wouldn't be able to access the array to pass it to the function, pretty much sends me back to my original problem. hmm

Comment: @Eddie no, it indicates you have a design problem. The finder method should likely be on that helper then.

Answer (score 4):

The answer as to why `global` seems to be not working is that CI's helper files are included into a function scope. In other words `$details` array is not in global scope, so `global` does not see it.

As to how you should do it instead - see other's answers.

Comment: That's what I assumed was happening +1 for the clarity

Answer (score 0):

In addition, you may consider to use Config class instead `global`. In that way, you have a static array variable and whenever you need it, just call CI Config function using CI super object `$ci =& get_instance();` in your helper.

Comment: I did think about this as another option, thanks for the input :)

Comment: That's pretty much the same as using the `global` keyword and should be avoided.

Comment: @Gordon, i think its depend to the situation he deals with. If he need that array, ONLY in related helper function then yes, using global scope is a bad idea. But consider other case, when he might use that array in other helper function, or in his model, or on his controller. Then save it into a config will be an efficient and reusable, instead putting an array everywhere.

Comment: @toopay Whenever you have to break encapsulation (and that's what it does), it's a sure sign your design is broken. If you need that array either pass it where it is needed or encapsulate the array into an object and place those methods on the object that operate on the array values.

Comment: I can't agree more with that aproach, convention over configuration (just like RoR in Ruby). But thats not how CI works i believe. Everywhere, in CI lib or class, you can see different approach, calling config everywhere. Its kinda, as you said, `broken design`. but it is what it is. Its a common aproach in CI, even i personally didnt like that too.